# Formula/constant to replace a table into just one formula

Tags: python, excel, vba, data-analysis, mathematical-optimization

In the below table I got some values where the column headers represent the density where the first column of the table represent a temperature.

| Density/Temp | 0.5 | 0.505 | 0.51 | 0.515 | 0.52 | 0.525 | 0.53 | 0.535 | 0.54 | 0.545 | 0.55 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2.5 | 1.051 | 1.05 | 1.048 | 1.047 | 1.046 | 1.045 | 1.043 | 1.042 | 1.041 | 1.04 | 1.039 |
| -2 | 1.05 | 1.049 | 1.047 | 1.046 | 1.045 | 1.044 | 1.042 | 1.041 | 1.04 | 1.039 | 1.038 |
| -1.5 | 1.048 | 1.047 | 1.046 | 1.044 | 1.043 | 1.042 | 1.041 | 1.04 | 1.038 | 1.038 | 1.037 |
| -1 | 1.047 | 1.046 | 1.044 | 1.043 | 1.042 | 1.41 | 1.039 | 1.038 | 1.037 | 1.037 | 1.036 |
| -0.5 | 1.046 | 1.045 | 1.043 | 1.042 | 1.041 | 1.04 | 1.038 | 1.037 | 1.036 | 1.036 | 1.035 |
| 0 | 1.044 | 1.43 | 1.042 | 1.041 | 1.04 | 1.038 | 1.037 | 1.036 | 1.035 | 1.035 | 1.034 |
| 0.5 | 1.043 | 1.042 | 1.04 | 1.039 | 1.038 | 1.037 | 1.036 | 1.035 | 1.034 | 1.033 | 1.032 |
| 1 | 1.41 | 1.04 | 1.039 | 1.038 | 1.037 | 1.036 | 1.035 | 1.034 | 1.033 | 1.032 | 1.031 |
| 1.5 | 1.04 | 1.039 | 1.037 | 1.037 | 1.036 | 1.035 | 1.034 | 1.033 | 1.032 | 1.031 | 1.03 |
| 2 | 1.038 | 1.038 | 1.036 | 1.035 | 1.034 | 1.033 | 1.032 | 1.031 | 1.03 | 1.03 | 1.029 |
| 2.5 | 1.037 | 1.036 | 1.035 | 1.034 | 1.033 | 1.032 | 1.031 | 1.03 | 1.029 | 1.029 | 1.028 |
| 3 | 1.036 | 1.035 | 1.033 | 1.033 | 1.032 | 1.031 | 1.03 | 1.029 | 1.028 | 1.028 | 1.027 |
| 3.5 | 1.034 | 1.033 | 1.032 | 1.031 | 1.03 | 1.03 | 1.029 | 1.028 | 1.027 | 1.027 | 1.026 |
| 4 | 1.033 | 1.032 | 1.031 | 1.03 | 1.029 | 1.029 | 1.028 | 1.027 | 1.026 | 1.026 | 1.025 |
| 4.5 | 1.031 | 1.03 | 1.029 | 1.029 | 1.028 | 1.027 | 1.026 | 1.026 | 1.025 | 1.025 | 1.024 |
| 5 | 1.03 | 1.029 | 1.028 | 1.027 | 1.027 | 1.026 | 1.025 | 1.025 | 1.024 | 1.023 | 1.023 |
| 5.5 | 1.028 | 1.028 | 1.027 | 1.026 | 1.025 | 1.025 | 1.024 | 1.023 | 1.022 | 1.022 | 1.022 |

Now my actual table is a lot bigger. Adding this all into a VBA module will make it terribly slow to open or to save.
Of course I can save the full table to a worksheet and cope as a lookup table. But it would be much better/cleaner to have it in a formula which can just generate the full table.

Is there some software available or some Python module where I could open the table as a csv file which would be analyzed and get some kind of formula constant.

---

I can understand it is not very clear. Is there some way to retrieve the factor from the table which is defined by the X and Y for a temperature and a density? X and Y would give you a coordinate which represents a value in this table.
Now the question is with the temperature and density if there would be a factor/formula to replace the table so I can calculate the value which is the coordinate for X and Y?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to find an approximation function, otherwise there's nothing to talk about. From what I can see, your data can be approximated by a linear formula.
[image]

We can use a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) or, in this case, the [method of ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares). Our final formula will look like `f(Density, Temperature) = k1*Density + k2*Temperature + k3`. But first, let's fix provided data.

[image]

Next, I suggest to [normalize data representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Put the Temperature parameter in a separate column. Use Power Query Editor to load your data and apply unpivoting temperature columns.

[image]

Then we have to add an additional column to the normalized data for a free coefficient k3 in the approximation formula. All its values should be equal 1.

[image]

And let's rename the table of unpivoted data, just for convenience. I named this table Data

[image]

After all preparation, put this formula in any cell on a new sheet:

```
=LET(MatrixA; Data[[Density]:[Coeff]]; MatrixB; Data[Value]; MMULT(MMULT(MINVERSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(MatrixA);MatrixA));TRANSPOSE(MatrixA));MatrixB))
```

In the result you'll get coefficients k1, k2, k3 for our desired formula.

[image]

I've got this result with provided data :

```
f(density, temperature) = -0.0025*density - 0.1783*temperature + 1.1329
```

The expected absolute value of error is `0.003` in this case.

For more details I recommend to watch this video:

- [Linear Regression With Multiple Variables and normal Equation, by Andrew Ng](https://youtu.be/B-Ks01zR4HY)
- [What is Regression? by Zedstatistics](https://youtu.be/aq8VU5KLmkY)
- [The Main Ideas of Fitting a Line to Data, by StatQuest](https://youtu.be/PaFPbb66DxQ)